# Gate controlled turn-on time

Tags: triac, dimmer, thyristor

Under DYNAMIC CHARACTERISTICS for [BT137](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BT137_SERIES.pdf) is Tgt value set to typically 2us.

If I then look under [BTA16](https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/haopinfsj489ydf945dt.pdf), I see no mention of the pulse width.

Is there a minimum pulse width as a standard value for all triac and thyristor, where there is nothing else mentioned?

And, will a to rapid trigger pulse destroy the gate?

Answer (score 1):

Too short a trigger pulse can cause hot spots to form in the thyristor structure and can damage the part.

I suggest some tens of microseconds minimum is a good choice for modest thyristors (up to 40A). Gate dissipation will be negligible.

A more limiting factor may be that if there is inductance in the circuit the thyristor current may not have time to build up to the holding current during the trigger pulse. In such a case you may not get the thyristor to conduct for the entire half-cycle of the mains- it will just briefly turn on during part of the trigger pulse then turn off again after.

Comment: Yes, I understood it after read about latching and holding, and also thought whether it about 90% to 10% regulation, where the fastest pulse could depend on the latching and holding current, unless there was a max frequency as witch the different transistors . Thank you.